# Laravel Form Set Default Selection

Tags: php, web, laravel

@section('page-action')

{{ Form::select('item_type', $product_type, null, ['id' => 'item_type', 'class' => 'form-control select ', 'required' => 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Type de produit']) }}

@endsection

**Hello everyone
If I make a change in the code I shared, it comes directly with 'Produits' selected.
I would be very grateful if you can help me with this.
Thanks for your help.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPQ99.png)